# flask_socketio not working with 'https' protocol

Tags: sockets, flask, flask-socketio

I am having error BAD REQUEST(in Console), when I run code using 'https' protocol

Server side:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for,
con = Flask(__name__) 
con.debug = True 
con.secretKey ='HelloWorld-ByeWorld' 
socket = SocketIO(con)
# MY code 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socket.run(con)
```

client Side:

```
socket=io.connect({secure:true});//default domain
privatedomain = location.protocol+'//'+document.domain+'/private';
videodomain = loaction.protocol+'//'+document.domain+'/video';
socket_private = io(privatedomain, {secure:true});
socket_video = io(videodomain, {secure:true});
getConnectedDevices('videoinput', cameras => console.log('Cameras found', cameras));
webcam();
```

But it works fine with 'http' protocol.
I need 'https' to work with media devices.

I am using ngrok for tunneling.

Comment: Flask-SocketIO does not provide a web server. The problem that you have is between the client and the web server that you are using. Check the client and server logs to see if there are any clues that help you figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying different version of `flask, flask-socketio`,  I have reached the conclusion that problem lies in `python-engineio` version. Beyond `python-engineio==3.8.2.post1` the 'https' fails to connect.
So for me, the best working package versions are-

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SocketIO==4.3.0
gevent==1.4.0
python-engineio==3.8.2.post1
python-socketio==4.5.1
```

ThankYou Miguelgrinberg, Yazaar for helping me out.